# Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<BreakpointState>'

Tags: angular

Using angular-material schematic, I want to generate the navigation menu. For that I use the following command:

```
ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name layout
```

When I serve my application, this error is thrown:

> error TS2322: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>     Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'BreakpointState'.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10960 I think, you should check this issue.

Comment: As I see, the issue is still open

Comment: There is [a PR that fixes this issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/11448/commits/20306dbeed3fe7232ffb85ba1d9fd406f6885db2) but not sure when it'll be merged. Maybe until that time, you can manually fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>*Adding an answer just to make this remove from unanswered ones.*</sub>

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10960) and fixed by [this pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10960).

Until this PR goes live, you can make changes manually.

`__name@dasherize__.component.html`

**From:**

```
[attr.role]="isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
[mode]="isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 'side'"
```

**To:**

```
[attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
[mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
```

---

```
__name@dasherize__.component.ts
```

**From:**

```
[attr.role]="isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
[mode]="isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 'side'"
```

**To:**

```
[attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
[mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
```

**From:**

```
isHandset$: Observable<BreakpointState> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
```

**To:**

```
isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change type of observable to boolean in your typescript file.
Match parentheses in your component html file
[attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
[mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"

here is the fix in Green Lines

[image]

Here is the main link of fix-https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/11448/commits/20306dbeed3fe7232ffb85ba1d9fd406f6885db2